# How to bind to Highcharts constructor/listen to CustomEvents from Vue component

Tags: highcharts, vue.js, vuejs2, highmaps

This map exists inside of a Vue component and what I'm trying to do is use

`this.$emit('somethingHappened', HighmapsEventObject)`

```
mounted () {
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: () => { 

          in here 

        }
      } 
    }]
  })
}
```

as in

```
mounted () {
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: () => { 

          `this.$emit('somethingHappened', HighmapsEventObject)`

        }
      } 
    }]
  })
}
```

But obviously, `this` at this point, references the Highmap's `this` not the Vue component's `this`

so I've tried to do something like this:

```
mounted () {
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: (e) => { 

          this.$emit('somethingHappened', e)

        }
      } 
    }]
  }).bind(this)
}
```

But I get:

`... default.a.mapChart(...).bind is not a function`

and I can't figure out how to pass the Vue component's `this` to the highmaps constructor and Vue doesn't naturally listen to `CustomEvent`s so I can't figure out how to dispatch the event in that callback so that Vue is aware that it happened.

```
mounted () {
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: (e) => { 
          let event = new CustomEvent('mapclicked', {
            detail: e
          })
          e.target.dispatch(event)
        }
      } 
    }]
  })
}
```

So my question, at long last, is how do I either a: listen for `CustomEvent`s in Vue, or b: bind Vue's `this` to a Highmaps constructor?

Thanks SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 options as far as i can see, you can use the infamous "that" variable

```
mounted () {
  const that = this;
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: () => { 
          that.$emit('somethingHappened', HighmapsEventObject)
        }
      } 
    }]
  })
}
```

you can create a function directly:

```
mounted () {
  const something = (HighmapsEventObject) => { this.$emit('somethingHappened', HighmapsEventObject); };
  Highcharts.mapChart(this.$el, { 
    series: [{ 
      events: {
        click: () => { 
           something(HighmapsEventObject);
        }
      } 
    }]
  })
}
```

Or you can use an event bus https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/ but that sounds like an overkill.

Finally you can try (if you aren't already) the highchart vue plugin: https://github.com/weizhenye/vue-highcharts